# Creating a favourites list using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I'm trying to implement a favourites list that gets the id of the current game that the user is looking at. So far I have this:

```
$('#favouriteBtn').click(function(){
    currentAddFav();
});

function currentAddFav(){
    if(localStorage.getItem('favourites')){//If there are favourites
        var storage = JSON.parse(localStorage['favourites']);
        for (var i = 0;i <= storage.length;i++){
            if(storage[i] == currentGame.id){//Id already stored, we dont want a duplicate id so ignore
                console.log('id already stored');
                break;
            }
            else{//game id doesn't exist in storage so add the id to storage
                storage.push(currentGame.id);
                localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(storage));
                console.log('must be a new id?');
            }
        }
    }else{//No favourites in local storage, so add new
        var favArray= [];
        favArray.push(currentGame.id);
        localStorage.setItem("favourites", JSON.stringify(favArray));
        console.log('New favourites list');
    }

}
```

If I try adding a new favourite it works, if I try adding the same favourite that was first added to the list, it works fine. Then if I try adding a different favourite than the one first added, the array in local storage allows me to keep adding new ids to it.

Comment: what is your question, what is failing?

Comment: @niklas basically I want to allow the user to only be able to add the favourite once to the array, I want to avoid duplicate ids, im currently getting duplicate ids, both the if and else statements under the loop are triggering each time i click, when it should just be one or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong

```
for (var i = 0;i <= storage.length;i++){
```

executes either the if or the else case for every item in the storage. What you would want is:

```
if (storage.indexOf(currentGame.id) == -1) { 
  # not found
  storage.push(currentGame.id);
  localStorage.setItem('favourites', JSON.stringify(storage));
} else {
  # found
  console.log('item already in favorites')
}
```

Comment: This seems to have solved my problem, thanks! So were basically saying that if the id doesn't occur inside the array; add it?

Comment: yes. look at your loop again and think what happens when you have e.g. the items `[2,3,4]` in your array and `currentGame.id = 4` you will execute the if...else... three times, where it will hit the else case twice (items 2 and 3) and then the if case once (item 4). So 4 will be added two more times to your array (else case)

Comment: So the way I had my loop it would perform actions for every number it iterated over until it reached its target?

Comment: I advice you look at it and play it through in your head or on a paper with different arrays of ids and current game.id s